# Problem with fetching JSON data from S3 and creating html list

Tags: javascript, html, json, amazon-s3, fetch

I have a json file being hosted on S3 that I am trying to pull and use to write links in an unordered list. When I test my json data by hosting locally, with json-server (on NPM), it works perfectly fine. However, when fetching from S3, it will not write out the list, even though the only difference is where the json is hosted. I worked out my permissions issues with S3 and I have gotten it to fetch successfully, as I was able to log the json data into the console, but cannot get it to create the list.

```
const jsonUrl_Q418 = 'http://localhost:3000/Letters';
fetch(jsonUrl_Q418)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    for(let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.innerHTML = '<a href=' + data[i].url + '>'+ data[i].name + '</a>'; 
      lettersList.appendChild(listItem);
    }
  });
```

If I change jsonUrl_Q418 to the s3 link, it will not work the same. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in your console? What is `lettersList`? It appears to be undefined

Comment: Your data is available in data.data.

Comment: lettersList was defined above this snippet. It is just a <ul> I had created. @DEVCNN thank you, I will check this when I get home!

Comment: @DEVCNN I tried doing a console.log(data.data) and got a TypeError.

Comment: The thing is i tried this with axios and that worked. So i hoped fetch might work as well. But fetch is a very different module. It is returning a buffer. You will have to read that buffer and convert it into json. I would recommend using axios,if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses fetch module. This should log your data. Note that the 'res' object is a buffer which can be read by converting it into a String. Now if you need the data as an object - JSON.parse(res.toString('utf8'))

```
fetch('https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/misc-csv/tslint.json',
function(err,meta,res){
  console.log('AXIOS:',(res.toString('utf8')));
  return JSON.parse(res.toString('utf8'))
});
```